# Sort array from object based on a property and return the sorted initial object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, ramda.js

I have the following object

```
{
  "object": "list",
  "url": "/v1/prices",
  "has_more": false,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "price_1KHlU72eZvKYlo2CblI51Z8e",
      "object": "price",
      "active": true,
      "billing_scheme": "per_unit",
      "created": 1642150211,
      "currency": "usd",
      "livemode": false,
      "lookup_key": null,
      "metadata": {},
      "nickname": null,
      "product": "prod_Kxgr3hZDfHnqu1",
      "recurring": {
        "aggregate_usage": null,
        "interval": "month",
        "interval_count": 1,
        "usage_type": "licensed"
      },
      "tax_behavior": "unspecified",
      "tiers_mode": null,
      "transform_quantity": null,
      "type": "recurring",
      "unit_amount": 2,
      "unit_amount_decimal": "2"
    },
    {...},
    {...}
  ]
}
```

How can I sort the *object.data* from it based on the *unit_amount* property and also keep the initial values of the object (url, has_more, ...)?

I've tried using Ramda, but it's giving me an new object just with the sorted data.

So I need object.data from the initial object to be sorted and to return the entire object after sorting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sort array of objects by string property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value)

Comment: `obj.data.sort(comparison_function)`

Comment: `sort` modifies the array in place, so sorting the `data` array won't have any effect on the other properties.

Comment: @Barmar yes, but it's not returning the rest of the props from the initial object

Comment: Try this approach `const newObj = { ...obj, data: obj.data.sort((o1, o2) => o1.unit_amount - o2.unit_amount) };`

Comment: You need to post your code.

Comment: `sort()` returns the array that it's sorting. Don't use the return value, just operate on the array and continue using the object normally.

Comment: @Barmar yeas, you are right! Thank you!

Comment: Also the solution from @AlexandrBelan works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple sorting, for example

```js
const obj = {
  "object": "list",
  "url": "/v1/prices",
  "has_more": false,
  "data": [
    {"unit_amount": 2,},
    {"unit_amount": 1,},
    {"unit_amount": 3,},
    {"unit_amount": 9,},
    {"unit_amount": 5,},
  ]
};

const newObj = { ...obj, data: obj.data.sort((o1, o2) => o1.unit_amount - o2.unit_amount) }; 

console.log(newObj)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects in Javascript have no inherent order to their properties, whereas arrays do, so I suggest you extract the data array, sort it, then replace the unsorted version in your object.   Something like this (object simplified for readability):

```
o = {
    "object": "list",
        "url": "/v1/prices",
            "has_more": false,
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "price_1KH",
                        "unit_amount": 12,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "price_7QW",
                        "unit_amount": 3,
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "price_4DD",
                        "unit_amount": 7,
                    },
                ]
}
let data = o.data;
data.sort((x, y) => x.unit_amount - y.unit_amount);
o.data = data;
console.dir(o);
VM694:23 
Object
data: Array(3)
0: {id: 'price_7QW', unit_amount: 3}
1: {id: 'price_4DD', unit_amount: 7}
2: {id: 'price_1KH', unit_amount: 12}
length: 3
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)
has_more: false
object: "list"
url: "/v1/prices"
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Answer (score 0):

Ramda will not make it easy for you to modify data, but if you want to create a copy of your input with a sorted copy of the array, that's pretty simple using the lens functions `lensProp` and `over`:

```js
const sortData = over (lensProp ('data'), sortBy (prop ('unit_amount'))) 

const obj = {object: "list", url: "/v1/prices", has_more: false, data: [{unit_amount: 2,}, {unit_amount: 1,}, {unit_amount: 3,}, {unit_amount: 9,}, {unit_amount: 5,} ]};

console .log (sortData (obj))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.2/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script>const {over, lensProp, sortBy, prop} = R </script>
```

Here we steal the simple input format from Alexandr Belan.  That answer already has some simple code.  I think this is simpler -- and it's definitely more declarative -- but I wouldn't bother with it unless I was already using Ramda in my application.